# Preferring {foo: bar} or {foo : bar} (extra space after :) style in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Are there any community consensus whether one should write

```
   {foo: bar}
```

or

```
   {foo : bar}
```

in Javascript.

Looks like JsHint doesn't care about matter.

For example, on Python, which has similar dictionary construct, the style without an extra space after the name is preferred.

This is a matter for consistency of the coding style in large open source code bases. I don't really care how the minified output looks like. I just to want to make sure my minions **produce consistent source code**.

Comment: It all gets minified eventually, right?  Then, why not spaces?

Comment: Because of the consistency and conventions in style

Comment: Good read http://addyosmani.com/blog/javascript-style-guides-and-beautifiers/

Comment: "I don't really care how the minified output looks like. I just to want to make sure my minions produce consistent source code." <devilsadvocate> _Why?_ </devilsadvocate>

Comment: +1 because you formulated and formatted this question very well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit presumably to make it easier for the rest of the team, and future developers, to work on each others' code

Comment: @KelvinMackay: It's always easiest to work on code that follows your preferred personal style, and cross-team consistency only makes coding easier for 50%* of that team. For the remainder, you've made it harder. [* figure obviously made up]

Comment: @KelvinMackay: For what it's worth, I'm a freaking zealot for consistency and code conventions, but I will always freely admit that, when asked _why_, I can never give a convincing answer to that question. That's why I'm asking it here.

Comment: The style you follow largely depends on the community, jQuery has their own guidelines (white space), and nodeJS community tends to have a different style (semicolonless, comma first). Go with what you feel more comfy, afterall minified code is the final output (front-end) and that'll be unreadable anyway.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit fair point, and I completely agree. I guess the process we use looks something like: Theory: "if everyone writes their code this way, everyone can read it" Reality: "if everyone writes their code this way, I can read it. And everyone else's way is wrong anyway."

Comment: @Kelvin: Indeed. See also: http://xkcd.com/927/

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is **no, there is no consensus**.

Comment: +1 I don't think there could be a more correct answer.

Comment: Please point a community style guide which prefers to write this with a space or your answer is factually incorrect.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: You cannot prove that there is a consensus by listing three sources that agree and demanding someone find a source that doesn't. i.e. you cannot prove a negative. _That said_, your research does indicate that the lack-of-space approach is more consistently adopted than I would have guessed. I'd go with it.

Comment: If there was a community style guide with a preference then his answer would be incorrect. As it stands, there is no community style guide, thus there is no consensus.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is decided

- Crockford goes without extra space.
- idomatic.js goes without extra space.
- jQuery prefers without extra space.

Thanks for elclanrs  for the pointers.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit goes without extra space

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep mind one thing, **development code is not production code**. Go ahead and use the extra space in your development code, but when you minimize that it is just going to become `{a:b}` anyway.

If your goal is to produce highly readable code that is consistent, then perhaps you should write a standard. Everyone does it slightly differently. Just look at how many module examples there are.

For example, why not do this?

```
var objectName = {};
objectName.foo = bar;
```

or this?

```
var objectName = function(){};
objectName.foo = bar;
```

Comment: Edited the question: please re-read